# Displaying number for each line not working

Tags: javascript, html, list, multiline

I'm trying to display the number of each line and add a given value to inputs with a click of a button. For example:

```
Anna
George
John
Doe
```

Would become

```
1,Anna
2,George
3,John
4,Doe
```

I tried the following piece of code, but it doesn't seems to work:

```js
function addNumber() {
  var content = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
  var line = 1;
  var replaced = content.replace(/^/gm, function() {
  return '<span class="line-number-position">&#x200b;<span class="line-number">' + line++ + '</span></span>';
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
<button onclick="addNumber()">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you are wanting? [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/ze7wrm8d/) No need for the `line` variable, You can just `+1` to the loop increment `i`

Comment: @NewToJS this is great! Thanks alot. Any idea how to add an input value as well? Eg. 1234,1,1,Anna where 1234,1, is a given value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give me a working example of some sort?

Comment: @NewToJS Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jd27xpuh/

Comment: You have multiple `textarea` elements. Can you explain your expectations of the clients input and expected outcome. Maybe if I understand the expected steps and results I might be able to make things more simple.

Comment: @NewToJS I have a list of names and I need to add some values in front of them. It's more like an update to make things work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192538/discussion-between-newtojs-and-jacob-k).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function addNumber() {
  var content = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
  var line = 1;
  var replaced = content.replace(/[0-9],/g, '').replace(/^/gm, function() {
  return line++ +',';
  })
  document.getElementById('myTextArea').value=replaced
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
<button onclick="addNumber()">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: This is a great answer but if you click the button more than once it will add the row count again. Maybe if you add `content.replace(/[0-9],/g, '')` before `.replace(/^/gm, function() {` this would be better? [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/dvxsf2ke/) Feel free to update your answer with those changes if you believe it will make things better.